# magento module with payment restriction

Tags: module, paypal, payment, magento-1.4

I have two payment methods on my magento, paypal and credit card but i wanna accept paypal just for order above $50.

how i can create this limitation? i tought maybe new mdoule which extend paypal and credit card modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend Paypal payment method model and override `isAvailable` method. This method accepts `$quote` object. You can get order totals from it. Then check if a required total is less than 50 then return false. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

> \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Standard.php Line 187

add the following to the if-condition:

> && Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() > 50